# How to scale out Vertices without changing the relative distance to one another

Tags: modeling, transforms

I want to move the center vertices outward without fattening the cylinders. The tops and bottoms should remain the same distance while the middle moves outward. When I scale the center vertices the cylinders fatten and it ruins the shape. I need them to stay the same thickness and slide outward along the x and y axis.

[image: my test model]

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos It has been fixed. Do you possibly have an answer to the question?

Comment: That is trivial to achieve with bezier curve objects, not so much with meshes

Comment: Do you want to keep the elliptical profile of the rods, or do you want them circular?